# Meaning of a small rectangle in schematic drawings

Tags: schematics, symbol

What is the meaning of the rectangle at the top of this schematic?

[image: this schematic]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yet another symbol for a rail or power supply voltage.  According to W5VO it means "This is the symbol for ultra-low voltage CMOS supplies of 1.2V"